# How to find singularities of $\cos(\frac{1}{z})\frac{\sin(z-1)}{(z^2+1)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to find singularities of $f(z) = \cos(\frac{1}{z}) \frac{\sin(z-1)}{(z^2+1)}$?

I'm going through practice problems in Agarwal's Complex Analysis book, and Exercise 30.3 on page 204 has the following exercise.  I have an approach that works for other problems, but not for this problem. I'm looking for howto refine my approach:

*Find and classify singularities of $f(z) = \cos(\frac{1}{z}) \frac{\sin(z-1)}{(z^2+1)}$*

My approach:

1. Find the points where $f(z)$ is not differentiable
2. For each of those points, expand the function $f(z)$ in Laurent series around those points.
3. see if any of the powers of $(z-z_0)$ (where $z_0$ is the singularity) cancel, and use the resulting series to classify the singularities.

Following the approach:

1. $z=i$, $z=-i$, and $z=0$ are all singularities, because cosine of $1/0$ is infinity.
2. expand $f(z)$ around each of those points
3. see if the powers of $(z-z_0)^n$ cancel with anything in the series expansion
4. classify.

For $z_0=\pm i$, I wasn't able to easily expand $cos(1/z)$ around $z_0= \pm i$ (and same for $\sin(z-1)$.   Is there an easier way to solve this problem?

Since I don't know the order of the pole beforehand, I don't know if I can compute the residue.

Is my approahc flawed?  And is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

Both $\cos(1/z)$ and $\sin(1-z)$ are analytic and non-zero on small enough neighborhoods of $i$ and $-i$. This means that $\frac{\cos(1/z)\sin(1-z)}{(z-i)(z+i)}$ has the same singularity types at $z = \pm i$ as $\frac{1}{(z-i)(z+i)}$.

Comment: Thanks @LeeFisher!  However, from my understanding $\cos(1/i)=\cos(-i)=0$.  so, it is *not* non-zero at $z=i$, right?

Comment: @nundo : $\cos(-\mathrm{i}) = \cosh(1) = 1.543\dots$.

Comment: Ah geez.  where is my brain today - thank you.  But in general, does it need to be analytic and nonzero at the singularity $z=z_0$?  Or only in the deleted neighborhood around it?  And how do we uncover the essential singularity at $z=0$?

Comment: So $f(z)$ has pole of order $k$ at $z = z_0$ if $(z-z_0)^k f(z)$ is analytic (actually, has removable singularity at $z_0$)  and non-zero in a neighborhood of $z_0$. In particular, suppose $f(z) = p(z)/q(z)$ and both $p$ and $q$ are analytic in a neighborhood of $z_0$. If at $z=z_0$, $p$ has a zero of order $n$ and $q$ has a zero of order $m$ then $f$ has a zero/pole of order $n-m$.

Comment: To get that the function has an essential singularity at zero notice that the Laurent series of $\cos(1/z)$ centered at zero has infinite negative order. The function $\sin(1-z)/(1+z^2)$ is analytic and non zero in a neighborhood of zero, so the product of the two functions must have an essential singularity at zero.